# What are the advantages of using a WAS (Websphere Application Server)?

Tags: web-server

Websphere caused me only pain! A JBoss/Tomcat on Windows works 3000% faster than a WAS on a big pseries server.

Websphere is big, slow and expensive.

Do you know really advantages of using it?

Comment: +1 for pain.  I feel your pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no first hand experience with WAS, but quite a bit with BEA Weblogic as a developper. I have the same kind of greifs toward WebLo as you have against WAS : slow to start, big, expensive, ... not very developper friendly.

But when it comes to production, I have to admit that I see the value of WebLo over Tomcat. The monitoring facilities are way better, ease of deployement (especially on a cluster), much better connection pooling ...

So yes, there are reasons why you might want to choose one of the big and expensive app server.

By the way, I found WebLo slow to start, but once it has started, everything is fine. I restart my dev server quite often, but not the production servers ...

Comment: WebSphere tools for monitoring etc. look only nice. But when you really need them, you'll end up in frustration.

Answer (score 2):

It has IBM support behind it which counts for a lot if your a large corporation. It's also written to support more platforms. If you already have a Mainframe you can run Websphere under Z/OS and leverage many of your system administrators mainframe skills to maintain it.

Answer (score 1):

It has IBM standing behind it.

Don't knoch the power of that, for many people the "feel good" element of commercial support is critical for them.

Comment: Is IBM support the only "feature" around there?

Answer (score 1):

- [Nobody ever got fired](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt) for buying IBM.
- It takes an [everything but the kitchen sink](http://www.big-bubbles.fluff.org/blogs/bubbles/archives/000374.html) approach to things, so it gets top score on most simplistic feature list comparisons.
- Support. Or more likely than not consulting, of course. And you'd better be running the latest version.

That said, I think Network Deployment is a rather good idea with actual added value. Not up to the price they're charging though, and it suffers from a mediocre implementation.

Think of what you'd like a multi-node app server to be able to do. Try to do that with ND - then watch it fail.